# How to Implement Timeout in BluetoothGatt.connect

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to connect existing Bluetoogatt connect using :

> ```
> BluetoothGatt.connect()
> ```

**according to documentation**

This method is used to re-connect to a remote device after or when the connection has been dropped.

If the device is not in range, the re-connection will be triggered once the device is back in range.

My situation is that I want to try to connect for specific time(if device is not in range) and after that abort that but present scenario is such that it continue connecting and connecting (No time Out).

How do I abort this after specific time?

Comment: It looks to timeout after 30seconds but I don't know how to control it.

Comment: No, Device is connected after 2 Minutes also

Comment: maybe we are into device specific stuff I was testing on a Nexus4, no real change with the Android version updates.

Comment: according to documentation BluetoothGatt.disconnect() Disconnects an established connection, or cancels a connection attempt currently in progress. but it still not able to stop it